# how to make ajax request from flash

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, flash

I need add item to cart from flash and i do it with URLRequest, but i should refresh the page after that =(
How i can request to ajax?
I have simplacms with ajax cart:

```
$('form.variants').live('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
    if($(this).find('input[name=variant]:checked').size()>0)
        variant = $(this).find('input[name=variant]:checked').val();
    if($(this).find('select[name=variant]').size()>0)
        variant = $(this).find('select').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/cart.php",
        data: {variant: variant},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#cart_informer').html(data);
            if(button.attr('data-result-text'))
                button.val(button.attr('data-result-text'));
        }
    });
    var o1 = $(this).offset();
    var o2 = $('#cart_informer').offset();
    var dx = o1.left - o2.left;
    var dy = o1.top - o2.top;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    $(this).closest('.product').find('.image img').effect("transfer", { to: $("#cart_informer"), className: "transfer_class" }, distance);  
    $('.transfer_class').html($(this).closest('.product').find('.image').html());
    $('.transfer_class').find('img').css('height', '100%');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer [here](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/bridge-to-flash#externalinterface) There are three ways to do it:

- FScommand
- ExternalInterface
- getURL